# Unable to find element on child div xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
<div class="gwt-Label WLFP WEEP" data-automation-id="promptOption" id="promptOption-gwt-uid-2" data-automation-label="Start" title="Start" aria-label="Start" role="link" tabindex="0">Start</div>
```

In our application after search we get bunch of search results which are basically clicable links, i am trying to find out search text like "Start" in above example and click on it.
My xpath `//div[@data-automation-id='promptOption']/` highlight the area but after that when i provide required text path it doesn't find that.

```
//div[@data-automation-id='promptOption']//span[contains(@text, 'Start')]
//div[@data-automation-id='promptOption' and text()='Start']
//div[@data-automation-id="promptOption"]//a[.='Start']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
//div[@data-automation-label="Start" and text()="Start"][1]
```

Comment: I did try that, it didn't work that way either. //div[@data-automation-id='promptOption'] does identify it but if i have 2 results it fail, so i have to do specific text after this xpath.

Comment: Post edited accordingly, can you try again?

Comment: Thanks @Gilles, that one worked. i guess [1] made the difference.